# Custom FancordionRunner does not compile. What's wrong?

Tags: fantom, afbedsheet

I am trying to compile a FancordionRunner modeled after MyFancordionRunner from the official [Fancordion user guide](http://pods.fantomfactory.org/pods/afFancordion/doc/#testBedSheetApps), however, the compiler throws this error...

```
/data/code/mypod/test/specs/WebFancordionRunner.fan(9,35):
Invalid args make(), not (|moneyToursRest::WebFancordionRunner->sys::Void|?)
```

Fantom compiler complains in the super(f) invocation:

```
new make( |This|? f := null ) : super( f ) { 
  f( this )
  outputDir = `target/specs/`.toFile
}
```

I have tried making the input parameter non nullable ( |This| f ) to no avail. Adding or removing the invokcation f(this) doesn't make any difference either. I have tried Fancordion v1.0.0 as well as the latest, v1.0.4

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [FancordionRunner.make()](http://pods.fantomfactory.org/pods/afFancordion/api/FancordionRunner#make) it seems `make()` doesn't take any parameters so the code can just be:

```
new make() { 
    super.outputDir = `target/specs/`.toFile
}
```

It seems example in the user guide is out of date - but this [commit](https://bitbucket.org/AlienFactory/affancordion/commits/51bd4990efe2e1723608e7f1418a2d7b34ab8230) updates it.